# What font does Annals of Mathematics use for the journal cover?

Tags: fonts

The Annals of Mathematics is published bimonthly by the Department of Mathematics at  Princeton University. I would like to know what font they use for "ANNALS OF MATHEMATICS" on the cover page. If there isn't an exact one, is there anything similar? [Here is a link to an example](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/):

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at similar questions on this site like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: Looks like Caslon Open Face.

Comment: @Bernard +1. The `C`, `O`, `F` and `E` are giveaways. See https://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/caslon-open-face/regular

Answer (score 2):

As @Bernard has commented, the title of the journal uses *Caslon Open Face Std Regular*. This is a commercial font (see https://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/caslon-open-face/regular, in particular, notice the uppercase letters `C`, `O`, `F` and `E`).

The rest of the cover (editors, publisher/institution) uses Computer Modern.